# Tooltip for hidden communities is not able to localize

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, localization, hidden-communities

If current community is hidden in the user profile page, tooltip says:

> This site has been hidden by you. Only you and moderators can see this link.
>
> [image: tooltip]

I can't find this text in Transifex DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[String](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/111651882?key=eecec08a27e56071d64153fa9931f607) has been recently added to Transifex. Thanks guys.

> [image: rus]